# How to set log scale for values less than one in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am graphing the following data using matplot lib:

```
x_val = [-(2**24), -(2**23), -(2**22), -2(21)]
y_val = [-1/2, -1/4, -1/8, -1/16]
```

I data relation is linear, but because of the step patten I want to use a log scale, base 2, for both the x and y axis of the graph.

I problem is that the y values are negative and between 0 and -1. This means that I can't use `symlog` because it uses a linear scale for values less than 10. I am wondering if there is another way to scale the axis that will give a log for decimal numbers. This is my code so far:

```
ax1.set_xscale('symlog', basex=2)
ax1.set_yscale('symlog', nonposy='clip')
```

[image: the resulting graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the value at which the scale changes to linear using `linthreshy` (or `linthreshx` on the x axis). See the documentation for [`set_yscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale) or [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/symlog_demo.html) for more information.

Here's an example, changing it to 0.01, which plots your data as a straight line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_val = [-(2**24), -(2**23), -(2**22), -(2**21)]
y_val = [-1./2., -1./4., -1./8., -1./16.]

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(1)

ax1.plot(x_val,y_val,'bo-')

ax1.set_xscale('symlog', basex=2)
ax1.set_yscale('symlog', nonposy='clip', linthreshy=0.01)

plt.show()
```

[image]